# Python class decorator, cannot use constructor

Tags: python, abstraction

So I have the following decorator code

```
class Factory:

    def __init__(self, cls):
        self.cls = cls

    def __instancecheck__(self, inst):
        return isinstance(inst, self.cls)

    def Produce(self):
        return self.cls()
```

And the following class code

```
@Factory
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    def method(self): pass
```

Which works great. Allows me to do stuff like

`Foo.Produce().method()`

Instead of

```
instance = Foo()
instance.method()
```

But now I cant use the class constructor normally

```
Foo(arg)
```

Gives the exception 'Factory object is not callable'. My question is the following: How can I make a decorator that allows me to instantiate the decorated class using its constructor, but also allows me to use a function in the decorator?

Alternative ways I'd rather not use:

1. Skip the constructor. Always use `<Class>.Produce()` (and use `*args`/`**kwargs` to make it abstract/reusable.
2. Use setters in all the classes, and make them return `self` so they can be chained.
3. Make a class containing the produce method and extend this class.

Comment: You could implement `__call__` on `Factory`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the benefit of the `Produce` method. The "stuff" you show that it lets you do is equivalent to `Foo().method()` on the undecorated class. You don't need to bind the instance to a variable unless you want to (though usually you do).

Comment: @Blckknght I feel pretty stupid now. Was very educational tho. Java, C#, PHP all dont allow it. So I assumed it was the same for python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is telling you all you need to know, just add a `__call__` method:

```
class Factory:
    # ...

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.cls(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You sir, just resolved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

If all you want to do is to add a `Produce` function to the class, you can rewrite your decorator like this:

```
def Factory(cls):
    def Produce():
        return cls()
    cls.Produce= Produce # add the function to the class
    return cls
```